# "Be accepted to" vs. "be accepted onto"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Do these variations mean anything different, or is one more correct?

> I have been accepted **onto** a course at the University of Stack Exchange
>
> I have been accepted **to** the Masters programme

Are there any other variations?

Comment: Correctness has no degrees. Something is either correct or incorrect. You could say *most appropriate* though.

Comment: _onto_ sounds archaic to my ears.

Comment: @Kris This seems at odds with Quirk and Svartvik's suggested 5-point gradience for acceptability of constructions. They deal with the reality that some people will accept as correct a construction that others won't. If we are to use a higher-level definition of correctness and incorrectness, there will be an awful lot of constructions in neither set.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth OLD-O *Acceptability*: "the **degree** to which something is agreed or approved of by most people in a society" (emphasis mine) http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/acceptability  *ibid.,* *Correct*: accurate or true, without any mistakes http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/correct_1?q=correct

Comment: @Kris 'Who says that "correct" is a binary predicate? It's just as incremental as any other adjective. And stop worrying about grammatical fo paz. You don't know enough to worry properly yet. – John Lawler' {[Is using “more correct” a grammatical faux pas?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/273112/is-using-more-correct-a-grammatical-faux-pas)}. // Didn't you spot the later example in OLD: 'He is always very correct in his speech.'? Or are we free to select just the sense we like best?

Answer (score 2):

"Accepted into a course" is the usual wording for these things.

Answer (score 1):

*Accepted into a course* is American English. *Accepted onto a course* is more common in British English.

Answer (score 0):

*Into* or *to* would be correct for both, with *into* the more usual in both cases.

*At* or *to* for "...accepted at the University...".