# Is using "more correct" a grammatical faux pas?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, comparatives, gradability

I caught myself saying "to be more correct", is this strictly possible given that something is usually correct or incorrect.
If this is a grammatical faux pas, what is it called?

Comment: There are degrees of anything, and everything is relative. Even "perfect" is relativized in the U.S. constitution: ". . . in order to form a **more perfect** union . . ."

Comment: Who says that "correct" is a binary predicate? It's just as incremental as any other adjective. And stop worrying about grammatical fo paz. You don't know enough to worry properly yet.

Comment: I shall worry improperly then!

Comment: Something can be partially correct (eg I say your name is Rolf of Schleswig-Holstein), so it can be more correct -- closer to being absolutely correct.

Comment: @JohnLawler That was an incredibly patronizing comment. Besides, he can spell "faux pas" and you can't

Comment: @SAH in John's defence, I passed a slightly off colour jibe at the first comment, to which he must have taken offence. I have since removed that comment, as it was not meant to offend.

Comment: Since no one has said it yet: whether or not it’s logically possible for something to be more or less correct than something else is completely orthogonal to whether or not _more correct_ is a **grammatical** faux pas (or fo pa, if you prefer—and @SAH, I can assure you that John knows how to spell _faux pas_, he just sports a rather idiosyncratic orthography sometimes). ‘More correct’ is **grammatically** perfectly fine, whether it makes any sense or not; grammar does not describe the logical, semantic content of what you say, only the structure of how you say it.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I assume the framing of this as a grammatical question is based on the fact that the "more unique" qualm is found in style guides rather than philosophy books

Comment: @SAH Probably yes—but style guides (as their name implies) deal with much more than grammar. In fact, they don’t deal very much with grammar at all.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Good point.

Comment: Comparatives in English are formed by adding er to the base word (unless the word is irregular, as in good, better, best.) Many, but not all, two syllable words add er. That said, you can't say: correcter. Ergo, you must use: more correct, just like comparatives for three syllable or more words: more beautiful, more serendipitous. Some two syllable adjectives can go either way. "correct" cannot. This is basic grammar... It is ***more correct*** to say that this is a basic grammar question rather than an English usage question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"More correct" is acceptable (especially in the adverbial form "More correctly"). That said, you will usually see "More accurate" instead.

Comment: Not much of an explanation.

Answer (score 4):

"More correct" is certainly used when talking of **forms of address**. For instance it is quite common to call a Church of England parish priest "Reverend" when speaking to them but [Debrett's](https://www.debretts.com/expertise/forms-of-address/professions/religion/) {if you follow the link scroll down to the table of forms of address at the end} would not recognise this as the correct form of address (it is correct in the US but not in the UK).

In general it is **more correct** to use "Vicar" but, sometimes, a parish priest is a "rector" rather than a "vicar" and calling a rector "Vicar" is not really correct (although you can't tell the difference if you haven't been told). It is also possible that a *rector* or *vicar* is also a *canon* or a *dean* (or even a retired bishop) and in those cases "Rector" or "Vicar" would not be the **truly correct** form of address, however the relevant one would still be **more correct** than "Reverend".

Fortunately people worry about such things less now than they used to do but the distinction between **correct** and **more correct** forms of address still exists.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I enjoyed reading it. One point of contention however, `Fortunately people worry about such things less now than they used to`, I would have added `Un` to the beginning of that statement.

Comment: @RolfofSaxony I consider it to be fortunate, not for linguistic reasons but because that sort of concern is driven mainly by adherence to strict class divisions. I feel much happier under modern social conditions than under the ones which dominated 1950s society.

Comment: Perhaps it is old fashioned but I prefer the attitude of "mean what you say, say what you mean".

Answer (score 1):

'More correct' is semantically questionable and you probably want to word it differently.

[Adjectives can be described as 'gradable' or 'absolute'.](https://www.englishgrammar.org/absolute-adjectives/). A gradable adjective has degrees of that quality. An absolute adjective either has the quality or does not, with no in between.

The color 'red' is a *gradable* adjective because the redness of an object can be placed on a scale. This one is red while this one is redder. The semantics of the adjective allow comparative and superlative syntactic constructions easily.

Another example of an *absolute* adjective is 'unique'. If there is only one of a particular kind, it is unique. It cannot be 'more unique' - it is already unique, and that's as far as it goes.

Absolute adjectives do not allow being made into comparative or superlative. You can say 'the final countdown' but not 'the most final countdown'.

There are not many absolute adjectives. As the saying goes, you can't be a little pregnant, you either are or are not. But within a set of pregnant women, some may be further along than others and one can very legitimately say that one is more pregnant than another. So many adjectives that seem logically absolute, allow a little grading in comparison.

Which brings us to 'correct'. We are all familiar with the idea that true/false or multiple choice questions on tests are either correct or not; there's only one right answer. But one can always make a thoughtful philosophical point in a particular situation. "This answer is correct, but this other answer is better - it is *more* correct.". That might work in some situations, but the situation you'd really have to explain yourself to make sure you're not committing a solecism. Making a comparative out of an absolute usually sounds bad and is a sign of not thinking things through.

**The adjective 'correct' is usually absolute, but there are situations where it can be thought of as gradable.**

As to what it is called when one uses a word incorrectly or, more charitably, in a nearby sense, that is:

> [catachresis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catachresis).

The rhetorical term for a grammatical error is

> [solecism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solecism).

Comment: If *correct* is an absolute adjective, it didn't start out that way. Here are the first two examples for "correct, adj., 3," defined as " In accordance with fact, truth, or reason; free from error; exact, true, accurate; right. Said also of persons, in reference to their statements, scholarship, acquirements, etc.," in the OED: 1705   J. Addison Remarks Italy Pref. sig. A4   Monsieur Misson has wrote a more correct Account of Italy..than any before him.
1713   H. Felton Diss. Reading Classics 42   Always use the most correct editions.
The next two also use similar forms.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin I'll grant that 'correct' can be used sometimes in a gradable sense (more likely than 'unique').  But it always seems like a catachresis to me, where 'accurate' would be a more accurate use for the situation. Also, note that "Monsieur Misson has wrote a more correct Account" would normally use 'written' so...

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin English didn't start out in the 17th century and correct is borrowed form of Latin correctus, past participle of corrigo, which cannot be graded. I may be *talking more and faster* non-sense than anyone else, but I can't be more talking, and a line cannot be straighter than straight. It can be straighter than not straight, in which case it is just straight. So if you call something more correct, you are calling the other thing false. You may call a line less curved, hence straighter, but that's inconsistent and should be avoided. Is -1 smaller than -2? Depends on the *measure*.

Comment: @vectory, it's an etymological fallacy that words borrowed from other languages have to retain their standards of use from that language. As it entered use in English, "correct" was not absolute. Even today, "more correct" makes grammatical sense in plenty of situations where something comes closer to a desired standard. If it ever raises semantic concerns, that is distinct from whether it causes grammatical ones. You are applying a narrow absolutist definition that doesn't actually correspond to how "more correct" is understood as a comparative. That's overprescriptive.

Comment: [Lots of other gradable v absolute questions on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=gradable+absolute)

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin *As it entered use in English, "correct" was not absolute* is that something you can back up? If it was immediately graded, or perhaps graded in medieval Latin already, I'd be a little surprised (on account of grammarians possibly objecting; have to wonder how old the debate is, too), but that's not really my point. I just wanted to mention the Latin, because it would be a fallacy to say the English invented it and call it quids. The heart of the word in form and sense stayed the same.

Comment: @vectory - see my initial post. Its earliest uses in English with the discussed meaning were comparative. Two other examples from related uses:

Comment: Whoops: one example: 1676   Dryden, Aureng-Zebe, Prol.:  "What Verse can do, he has perform'd in this, Which he presumes the most correct of his." (I'm not about to call literary author/Latin grammarian John Dryden wrong here.) The "heart of the word" did not stay the same with respect to its use with the comparative.

Comment: @TaliesinMerlin from my search it seems you say "most correct" was used first, before the adjective "correct". That is weird, and hard to believe, to say the least. "correct" is found as verb much earlier though, if only the results were comprehensive, which they are not, not finding your Dryden quote, only later editions and mentions..At the end of that verse Dryden also wrote the line "Does, with disdain, the foremost honours yield." Comparing "most prized", I think my point about participles is still considerable, though less certain concerning the Latin.

Answer (score -1):

All the comments suffer the same error - they confuse **accurate** and **detailed** with "**correct**".

2+2 = 4: this answer is **correct**.
(i) 2+2 = 5; (ii) 2+2=5,681 -> neither answer is "**more correct**" but (i) is more accurate.

You can make up an example for "detailed" yourself.

**Correct** is an absolute state.

Comment: Not every use of correct refers to mathematics. It is more correct to say that in mathematics, calculations are correct or incorrect.

Comment: @Lambian, you needlessly denigrate the power of logical thought. Logic is chiefly, but not solely, in the domain of Mathematics. To say something were *more 90 degrees* simply isn't equal to *closer to 90 degrees*.

Comment: @vectory: We're not talking about the modifier *90 degrees* here, or even the modifier *perpendicular*. We're talking about the modifier *correct*. And I certainly agree that saying *more correct* for math problems is a logical mistake, but it's not a grammatical mistake.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer. It seems people think logic is a democracy and they get to use "more correct" simply because it sounds fine to them. They use "more correct" when they think "more accurate". Which is wrong. The adjective "correct" has no comparative forms. Either something is correct or it isn't.